# DB design for a rating system without duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a site in which people posts articles and users can read, comment on it. I want to add a 5-star rating system, and I want to prevent a user from rating on same article twice.

I know I can create a table with article_id and user_id of the person who has rated, thus preventing him from rating again. However this table can easily become very bloated with huge number of records. Is there any other architecture that anyone here is acquainted with to handle this in a more optimised way?

Any pointers is greatly appreciated. I only have access to MySQL database at the moment, so a key-value lookup store is currently not possible.

Comment: user_id, article_id, rating_id is still the best idea for now even if you will end up in 1M records. This should be pretty fast

Comment: In the table where you store the ratings, create a unique key on user and article ID. If you then try to insert a new rating for a specific user and article ID, it will fail. Also, you should join to this table when displaying the rating icons/button/etc. so if a user has already rated the article, you can disable the UI feature.

Comment: Also, even with many records, storing the ratings by article and user ID is very efficient. Basically a user ID *int(11)*, article ID *int(11)*, and rating *tinyint(1)*, and maybe a timestamp *timestamp*. So each row is small, and the unique key (index) will make joins and lookups very fast.